# "view my developer story" button visible even if tab is set to invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story

Presumably anyone who doesn't want the tab also doesn't want the button? Or was this by design?

In this screenshot I've turned off the tab, and the button still shows.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Could we blame cache? Or you set the option long ago?

Comment: Pretty sure the option is only to disable the tab next to profile and activity, I guess they forgot about the button.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub not as far as I can tell

Comment: Its intended, eventually you are likely to press it by accident and then you may reconsider using Developer Story.

Comment: Used to be the same thing with CVs too, guess they have just replaced the placeholder with the new one

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your input! We agree that it doesn't make sense to see the "View my Developer Story" button on your own profile if you have hidden your developer story tab. We have pushed a fix which will go live with the next production build.